# Getting the flavor of honey without the sweetness

Tags: honey

Honey has an interesting flavor, but it's very sweet.

Is there any way to get the flavor of honey without it being sweet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What comes to mind immediately is to experiment with different varieties. Honeys vary a lot in sweetness and strength of flavor.

From [About.com](http://localfoods.about.com/od/recommendedproducts/a/Honey-Flavors.htm)

- Acacia honey is very sweet with a clean, pure, classic honey flavor.
- Alfalfa is a light honey but with a nice mild spicy note and floral aroma.
- Blueberry honey has a slight tang and a fruity flavor.
- Buckwheat is tasty on toast, but its strong and spicy flavor makes it perfect for marinades.
- Clover is the classic honey - light, sweet, floral.
- Coffee honey tends to be quite dark, with a rich, deep flavor that matches its color.
- Eucalyptus honey has just a hint of menthol flavor in it, making it perfect for stirring into tea.
- Fireweed honey has a markedly complex flavor and a slightly buttery texture. Like buckwheat honey, it can stand up to meats, marinades, glazes, and grilling
- Heather is pungent and almost bitter, in a good way. It's great with smoky things, or on wholesome baked goods.
- Linden honey is quite delicate and has a fresh, woodsy aroma perfect with tea
- Orange Blossom is widely available but watch out, much of the orange blossom honey on the market is artificially flavored. Real orange blossom honey is mild and citrus-scented.
- Palmetto is a mild honey with balanced sweetness.
- Sage is a lot like palmetto honey - mild, sweet, flexible.
- Sourwood is caramel-like and buttery and delicious on toast, biscuits, muffins, and any other vehicle you can think of.
- Tupelo honey is somehow sweeter than other honeys, but with a lovely balanced mild flavor.
- Wildflower honey is light and fruity yet richly flavored at the same time.

Based on that, perhaps [heather honey](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_8?url=search-alias%3Dgrocery&field-keywords=heather%20honey&sprefix=heather+%2Cgrocery%2C483) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Wow!  I had no idea there were so many kinds of honey.  If youre ever tried it, does coffee honey taste at all like coffee?

Comment: @Prime I have not tried coffee honey, or even seen it. It's one of the few on that list I haven't tried. I also haven't tried heather, and I'm pretty curious about that.